# How can I limit git-diff to one directory only, without its children?

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm using `git diff --name-status` to track which files have been modified/added/removed/renamed/copied between two commits, and it works great.

Now suppose I move file `file1` to `newdir/file1`, commit, and then run git diff, I get this:

```
$ git diff --name-status -C HEAD~1 HEAD
R100    file1    newdir/file1
```

Is there a way to ask git to limit itself to the list of changes inside a given directory but not its children? I'd like to know the exact changes both for the root directory and for the `newdir`directory, separately. For `newdir`, it's easy:

```
$ git diff --name-status -C HEAD~1 HEAD -- newdir
A       newdir/file1
```

… but how can I obtain the "complementary" diff info in the root directory? I.e., this output:

```
$ git diff ???
D       file1
```

Note that I want to keep the `-C` option to detect renames and copies inside the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it through to grep:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD..HEAD~1 . | grep ^[^/]*$
```

This will filter out anything that contains a sub directory, if you need to get something from a deeper  do this:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD..HEAD~1 <path> | grep ^<path>[^/]*$
```

You could easily alias this if you wanted to.

Comment: `git diff <branchA>..<branchB> -- <path>` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know its probably doable in git, but I would be tempted to use the filterdiff/grepdiff programs from [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) something like this should work ok

```
git diff -C .... | filterdiff --clean -x '*/*/**'
```

Comment: The output of `git diff --name-status` is not a patch file, but a list of modified files only, so it seems like `filterdiff` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If running a Linux or compatible shell with `find` available, you can use `find` to generate the list of non-directory files in the current (or other) directory, then feed that to `git diff`, e.g.:

```
git diff --stat --other-git-diff-args -- $(find . -type f -depth 1 -print0 | tr '\0' ' ')
```